# Do one to many relational pouch instances always have to be updated on both ends?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pouchdb, relational-pouch

If I add a book to a relational pouch instance (That already contains an author with id 1 that has books 6 and 7) like this:

```
then(function() {
  return db.rel.save('book', {
  title: 'Winny the Pooh',
  id: 8,
  author: 1
})
```

And subsequently log the author query like this:

```
}).then(function() {
  var result = db.rel.find('author', 1);    
  result.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

The result is this:

```
{ authors: 
   [ { name: 'George R. R. Martin',
       books: [Object],
       id: 1,
       rev: '1-f07514693adc67c175bb1919b979dfcd' } ],
  books: 
   [ { title: 'A Game of Thrones',
       author: 1,
       id: 6,
       rev: '1-a36627090c454eba8ded42464ecfd37a' },
     { title: 'The Hedge Knight',
       author: 1,
       id: 7,
       rev: '1-1b725f45b6c9db0798a49f713dfaa5c6' } ] }
```

It does not look like `Winny the Pooh` was added to author 1's books, even though the object specifies that `Winny the Pooh` belongs to author 1.  Do I need to manually update author one with the id of the book `Winny the Pooh`?

I'm pasting the full test script below for reference:

```
var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
PouchDB.plugin(require('relational-pouch'));

var db = new PouchDB('mydb');
db.setSchema([
  {
    singular: 'author',
    plural: 'authors',
    relations: {
      books: {
        hasMany: 'book'
      }
    }
  },
  {
    singular: 'book',
    plural: 'books',
    relations: {
      author: {
        belongsTo: 'author'
      }
    }
  }
]);
db.rel.save('author', {
  name: 'George R. R. Martin',
  id: 1,
  books: [6, 7]
}).then(function() {
  return db.rel.save('book', {
    title: 'A Game of Thrones',
    id: 6,
    author: 1
  });
}).then(function() {
  return db.rel.save('book', {
    title: 'The Hedge Knight',
    id: 7,
    author: 1
  });
}).then(function() {
  return db.rel.save('book', {
    title: 'Winny the Pooh',
    id: 8,
    author: 1
  })
}).then(function() {
  var result = db.rel.find('author', 1);
  result.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data)
  });
}).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is no.  This [issue contains the answer details](https://github.com/nolanlawson/relational-pouch/issues/78).  I'll paste the final working script below.

```
    var PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
    PouchDB.plugin(require('relational-pouch'));
    PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-find'));

    var db = new PouchDB('mydb');
    db.setSchema([
      {
        singular: 'author',
        plural: 'authors',
        relations: {
          books: {
            hasMany: {
              type: 'book',
              options: {
                queryInverse: 'author'
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }, {
        singular: 'book',
        plural: 'books',
        relations: {
          author: {
            belongsTo: 'author'
          }
        }
      }
    ]);
    db.rel.save('author', {
      name: 'George R. R. Martin',
      id: 1
    }).then(function() {
      return db.rel.save('book', {
        title: 'A Game of Thrones',
        id: 6,
        author: 1
      });
    }).then(function() {
      return db.rel.save('book', {
        title: 'The Hedge Knight',
        id: 7,
        author: 1
      });
    }).then(function() {
      return db.rel.save('book', {
        title: 'Winny the Pooh',
        id: 8,
        author: 1
      })
    }).then(function() {
      var result = db.rel.find('author', 1);
      return result.then(function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      });
    }).catch(console.log.bind(console));
```